# Как определяется значение указателя this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, в чем разница между вызовами:

```
jQuery('div').each(obj.func);
```

и

```
jQuery('div').each(function() {
    obj.func();
});
```

Почему в первом случае `this` внутри `obj.func()` ссылается на `jQuery` объект `div`, а во втором - на объект `obj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае Вы передаете ссылку на функцию, и вызывающий код вызывает ее с контекстом, который этот вызывающий код определяет.

Во втором случае, вызывающий код делает то же самое с анонимной функцией, а метод `func` Вы вызываете сами в контексте `obj`.